# Does soy milk need a hechshir

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification

Does soy milk need a hechshir since they put in artificial things that can be trayf or its all natural and it won't need a hechshir

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. While you're at it, I recommend that you [edit your profile](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/8772) and give yourself a name.

Answer (score 4):

Per London Bais Din website:

"All plain soya milk is permitted. Other types of Dairy Free Milk are permitted if listed as approved or certified"

http://www.kosher.org.uk/koshersearch

However this may be limited to their region.

In the US, both OU and Star-K indicate that a hechsher is needed.

Answer (score 3):

I am summarizing points from [here](http://www.livingnaturally.com/promog/cluster.asp?cpid=98&storeID=A0DD6E45F03A4BD78C10790DCF9FC1A7) and [here](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-thirst-formula.htm),

Star - K points out that sometimes vitamins, which may be added to the soy milk, may originate from non-kosher sources.

The other article from Silk, says:

> All Silk products including Silk Creamer and Silk Live! Soy Yogurt are
>   completely dairy-free and safe for people with dairy allergies. None
>   of our ingredients are made from animal products, by-products or
>   derivatives. Our natural flavors do not contain any dairy or other
>   animal products.
>
> Are Silk products kosher?
>
> All Silk brand products in all flavors are certified Kosher OU-D.
>   Kosher OU-D certifies that a dairy-free product was heated on
>   equipment also used for dairy, and designates that dairy-free products
>   heated on equipment also used for dairy may not be eaten together with
>   a meat product. It may be eaten immediately after a meat product, but
>   not together. Since Silk products are dairy-free, why is the Kosher
>   certification OU-D?
>
> All Silk products including Silk Creamer and Silk Live! Soy Yogurt are
>   completely dairy-free and safe for people with dairy allergies. While
>   Silk soy products do not contain dairy ingredients, they may be
>   produced on equipment that also produces dairy products. Silk follows
>   strict allergen cleanup procedures to ensure products made on shared
>   equipment are dairy-free.
>
> Silk is certified Kosher OU-D, meaning they are dairy-free products
>   made on dairy equipment. The D designates that the dairy-free product
>   was heated on equipment also used for dairy and may not be eaten
>   together with a meat product. It may be eaten immediately after a meat
>   product, but not together.

So, it seems that a product such as Silk, which is completely vegan, according to its claim may not, per se, require a hechsher because of the nature of its ingredients. But, the 2 problems - i.e. - not knowing the source of its calcium (vitamin) ingredient and that it was produced together with diary items on the same equipment, is what requires the hechsher.

Related info: For many years, OU had a certification "DE" meaning "Dairy Equipment" on certain products. Because this hechsher confused many people, about 3 years ago, OU stopped using the "DE", and now even products, such as Silk soy milk, is marked plain OU-D. In the case of the soy milk, this is a bit misleading, as it is not dairy. However, OU has taken extra precautions and made it seem as if it is.

Hence, if you find a product marked OU-D and from the ingredients, there does not appear to be dairy ingredients, you need to contact the OU (or a rav who knows that product) to verify its status.

Comment: Ironically, by marking it OU-D they have probably thereby permitted it to be eaten with milk (since it won't be made to be eaten with milk and Stam Keilim Einan Benei Yoman, cf http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-kosher-cons-handbk.htm esp fn. 15).

Answer (score 1):

The current [Star-K list](http://star-k.org/cons-appr-no-need.htm) of items that do not need certification does not include soymilk.

This leads me to believe that a Hashgacha is required for soy milk.